# Pdf view within android application

Tags: android

I want to create an android application to open pdf within my android application. pdf is already downloaded in my device.I don't want to use url. Can anyone help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Show your effors. What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview use this github link for downloading the pdf library. it will open pdf within the app and it is very easy to use. it works fine for me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 File file = new File(your file path); 

  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                intent.setPackage("cx.pdf.android.pdfview");
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf2");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i don't want to use any other application to open pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Will this help you?

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl("file:///sdcard/path/to/your/pdf.pdf");
```

Comment: no actually this requires url,and i want to open downloaded pdf

Comment: the 'url' starts with file:/// and it will open the file you want. For example: webView.loadUrl("file:///sdcard/mypdffile.pdf");

Comment: there is an error "webpage "file:///sdcard/test.pdf" not found

Comment: Have you got a file at /sdcard/test.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this link for the Android PDF Viewer lib , this is a libray with example that you can implement your own PDF reader application.

https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

Answer (score 0):

You may use muPDF library it's a good library for PDF task, I used the same in my app https://github.com/muennich/mupdf follow the link.